# name 'balance' is used prior to global declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
pin = input("Set your PIN: ")
balance = 1000
wrong = 1

def service():
  nextt = int(input("\nWelcome! \n Press 1 - to withdraw some money and \n 
                    Press 2 - to exit the service \n Press 3 - to show 
                    current balance \n "))
  if nextt == 1:
    amount = int(input("\nHow much money do you want: "))
    if amount > balance:
      print("Sorry, but your current balance is only: " +str(balance)+" $")
      service()
    else:
      print("You withdraw: " +str(amount) +" from your account and your 
             current balance is: " +str(balance-amount)+" $")
      global balance
      balance -= amount
      service()
  elif nextt == 2:
    print("Thank you for your visit // exiting...")
    return
  elif nextt == 3:
    print("Your current balance is: " +str(balance)+" $")
    service()
  else:
    print("\n Failure: Press 1 to withdraw some money, 2 to exit the service 
          and 3 to show current balance!")
    service()

def card():
  global wrong
  choose = input("\nEnter your card PIN: ")
  if choose == pin:
    service()
  else:
    print("\n You entered the wrong PIN!")
    wrong = wrong + 1
    if wrong > 3:
      print("\n You reached the max. amount to enter your PIN correctly, 
            exiting...")
      return
    else:
      card()


card()
```

I can't fix this particular mistake:

```
on line 14: balance -= amount
```

I want to update the balance after withdrawing some cash, but it says:

```
  local variable 'balance' referenced before assignment
```

I added

```
  global balance 
  balance -= amount
```

new error:

```
name 'balance' is used prior to global declaration
```

all I want to do is: update the current balance after withdrawing some cash there!

Comment: Why not move `global balance` to the top of the function definition (instead of burying it in an `else` clause)?

Comment: you're absolutelly right, i mean look at the card function, global wrong, i did this one right, and messed up the service function OMG xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several lines above, you implicitly inform Python that `balance` is a local variable:

```
if amount > balance:
```

It hasn't been seen before in this name space (the function scope), so it's a local variable.  When you get into the `else` clause, you suddenly give Python this little "I lied" dance, declaring it to be global.  Python is not amused at such antics.

If you want `balance` to be a global variable (bad practice), then declare it as such at the top of the block, as suggested in the coding guidelines.  Better yet, pass it in as a function parameter and return it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's handy to list exactly what code is being ran:

```
nextt = int(input("\nWelcome! ..."))  # "nextt" is being set in the local scope
if nextt == 1:                        # "nextt" is being compared to 1
    amount = int(input("\nHow ..."))  # "amount" is being set in the local scope
    if amount > balance:              # "amount" is being compared to "balance"
                                      # Uh oh! We haven't defined "balance" yet!
        print("Sorry, ...")
        ...
```

To fix this, you can use the `global` keyword, which looks for the variable in the global scope. Lets look at an example of how this works before getting to the solution:

```
def f1():
    a = 2
    print("Value of a: {}; ID of a: {}".format(a, id(a)))

def f2():
    global a
    print("[Before] Value of a: {}; ID of a: {}".format(a, id(a)))
    a = 3
    print("[After] Value of a: {}; ID of a: {}".format(a, id(a)))

>>> a = 1  # we define "a" in the global scope

>>> a, id(a)  # id(variable) gets a unique value for this variable
(1, 1635934432)

>>> f1()
Value of a: 2; ID of a: 1635934464  # So you see that the ID is different, because this is f1's version of "a", not the global one

>>> a, id(a)
(1, 1635934432)  # the value and ID of the global variable remain unchanged

>>> f2()
[Before] Value of a: 1; ID of a: 1635934432  # see the value and ID of the local "a" are now the same as the global variable
[After] Value of a: 3; ID of a: 1635934496  # we replaced the value and ID here

>>> a, id(a)
(3, 1635934496)  # which has affected the global version now as well
```

Finally, the full solution:

```
global balance                        # "balance" is set to the global value
nextt = int(input("\nWelcome! ..."))  # "nextt" is being set
if nextt == 1:                        # "nextt" is being compared to 1
    amount = int(input("\nHow much ...: "))  # "amount" is being set
    if amount > balance:              # "amount" is being compared to "balance"
        print("Sorry, ...")
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix (if you insist on a global variable), is to relocate the global statement to the the first statement in your `def service` function:

```
def service():
   global balance
```

Your code uses globals quite liberally, which is a bad idea.  Other suggestions have been made to rectify that, so I won't expand on that any further :)